# How to get the units for the coordinates of an sp object in R

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sp

One can see the units for a projected sp object in R using `proj4string` for example:

```
> proj4string(myObject)
[1] "+proj=lcc +lat_1=44 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
```

But is there an easy way to get just the unit?

Comment: You should include an example with your question. How did you create `myObject`?. You could provide the output of `dput(myObject)` or you could create a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a cleaner way but that did the trick for me:

```
unit <- gsub(".*\\+units=(.*) .*","\\1",proj4string(veg))
```